# dynamically insert <br> or <p> using contenteditable based on the current tag

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I am trying to dynamically switch between `<br>` and `<p>` in contenteditable.

Basically, when I am pressing 'enter' key inside 'h1' tag (or any of h tags), it should insert `<br/>`, otherwise, it should insert `<p>`

I know I can switch to `<p>` using

`document.execCommand('insertBrOnReturn', false, true);`

But I don't know how I could this dynamically?

Comment: document.activeElement tells you what's being worked on. you check its say, tagName in your execCommand wrapper, and set the value accordingly, or inject HTML instead of using the break feature.

Comment: thanks @dandavis, however, document.activeElement does not give the exact tag while inside a contenteditable div. document.activeElement only works for input, textarea tags.